System.getProperty always returns null for defined property
I faced a problem, that i can't set a system property.
Simple example:
@Test
void newTest() {
System.out.println(System.getProperty("newProp")
}

I run it with gradle test -DnewProp=works.
On my personal laptop it returns works, but on corporate laptop it returns null.
It returns value from -D only if i set property in build.gradle like this:
test {
    systemProperty "new", System.getProperty("new")
}

But my personal laptop don't need it! I tried this on similar versions of Java/Gradle. But still corporate laptop needs changes in build.gradle, and personal don't, why?

How to give System property to my test via Gradle and -D
